# Missing /home folder in text mode Grub boot

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

Heyo - I am a bit of a novice to Gnu/Linux so please excuse me if I get anything wrong.

Essentially, I was trying to install NVIDIA drivers on Lubuntu. I couldn't use the recommended method, because Lubuntu removes the method suggested, and I disabled the default drivers not knowing they would cause a black screen.

To fix this I got a bootable USB and went to my drive, which was unmounted, and changed the /etc/default/grub file to boot in text mode. But I could not run grub-update normally, so I used chroot and did it from there. It threw some errors, but still updated the config file.

Then, when I booted the machine in text mode to install the drivers, I found the system failed to mount correctly, and I cannot locate the bin or sbin folders. In addition my /home folder is missing, which is where the driver files are located, so I can no longer install the new ones.

I am using default Lubuntu with LQXt Desktop env.

Enclosed is an image of what happens when I try to rectify the error
[image: SH fails to find nano or sudo commands]

Comment: Welcome! `(initramfs)` is not the GRUB console, so you can't do what you want to do from there. Does the GRUB menu show when you boot the machine? If so you need to press `e` and then `F2` to access the GRUB console `grub>`.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222310/931617) on how to boot from GRUB console, then we'll see from there.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I have gotten into the grub console but now can no longer run the installer